# Removing line numbers with sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have a file with following format:

```
1         LOAD INTO TABLE
2             TBLNAME
3          (
4          FLDR_NUM                               POSITION(       1         )
5          INTEGER                                      ,
4          FLDR_NUM                               POSITION(       5         )
5          INTEGER                                      
6          )
```

I need to get rid of line numbers, read field info and build a json like structure. As first step, I am doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
    name=$(sed -e 's/^[0-9][0-9]?\s*//' <<< $line)
    count=$[$count+1]
    # if [ $count -gt 3 ]
    # then
      echo "Name $name"
    # fi
done < $1
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve: Essentially remove until the first non-whitespace character after line numbers: 
Eg for line 4:

```
FLDR_NUM                               POSITION(       1         )
```

Updated the regex.

Comment: Use a language better suited to this type of parsing and data processing: Python, Perl, Ruby, C,... pretty much anything except shell.

Comment: thanks @chepner, It seems easier to switch to something like python than to deal with this inconsistency!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this so many ways.  One of the easiest might be just to use bash alone:

```
$ while read num line; do echo "$line"; done < inputfile
```

This works by considering each line as two variables separated by whitespace.  The first works out to be the line number.  The second is everything else.

A sed-based solution that is portable (i.e. not just for GNU sed) would look like this:

```
sed -e 's/^[0-9][0-9]*[[:space:]][[:space:]]*//' inputfile
```

Note that we use the BRE construct `[[:space:]][[:space:]]*` instead of the simpler ERE construct `[[:space:]]+` because *every* version of sed understands BRE, whereas not every one understands ERE.

If there is a risk of whitespace before the numbers you want to strip, then you can insert `[[:space:]]*` after the `^` in the substitution's regex.

Comment: thanks this works. As @chepner suggested, I am going to switch to python to make my life easier

Answer (score 1):

Sed is thinking that you're using the `(` metacharacter (a group). To use a literal `(`, you just need to stop escaping it:

```
sed -e 's/^[0-9][0-9]?\s*(*//'
```

---

It seems like this is the command you want: `s/^[0-9][0-9]?\s*//`

It will remove any one or two-digit numbers on the beginning of a line, followed by any number of spaces. If you want to get one-or-more numbers (instead of just one or two), change `[0-9][0-9]?` to `[0-9]\+`.

```
$ sed -e 's/^[0-9]\+\s*//' < example.txt

LOAD INTO TABLE
TBLNAME
(
FLDR_NUM                               POSITION(       1         )
INTEGER                                      ,
FLDR_NUM                               POSITION(       5         )
INTEGER                                      
)
```

EDIT: according to @ghoti, this isn't portable to every `sed` implementation

Comment: thanks. but why is that expression not replacing characters? I see it still printing the line numbers

Comment: Please add the expected result after the `sed` to the question

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I think because `\s` is not universal.  What flavour of sed are you using?

Comment: Because it doesn't work for me.  If you're going to provide an answer that requires a particular flavour of version of a tool, you should qualify it so that people know your solution isn't portable.

Comment: Here is the sed version information: `$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.

GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-gnu-utils@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
`

Comment: Sorry about that, but I couldn't imagine this would have issues in other versions on `sed`, I never had any issues using `\s`, neither in sed or any other regex engines. I will edit the answer accordingly. Also, I find it strange that it works with GNU 4.2.2, but not 4.2.1

Comment: @ghoti Added portability note. Is there anything I can add to the answer that makes you remove the downvote?

Comment: Downvote removed.  Note that I claim that this was a GNU-only solution, only that it was not portable.  It's entirely possible that other non-GNU implementations of sed have included these "character class shortcuts".  I don't know every sed implementation.

Comment: TBH, I don't know whether this is a POSIX thing.  I do know that [sed is supposed to use BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html#tag_04_126_13_02) and [BRE supports classes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03).  But I don't know when the convention of [character class shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) began.  Whether it's supported is up to the author of the regex parser, so it may vary from system to system, and so shouldn't be used if you want your regex to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be easy in `sed`. I mean, getting rid of the leading numbers and whitespace is easy, but the rest of what you want to do is going to be tough.

I would be more likely to choose `awk`:

```
awk -F'[ )(]+' '
    NF==2 && /[A-Z]/    {print "{ " $2 " => "                   }  # TBLNAME
    NF==5 && $2!="LOAD" {fldr_num=$2; pos=$4                    }  # FLDR_NUM/POSITION
    NF==3               {print "\t" $2 "/" fldr_num "/" pos "," }  # INTEGER
    END                 {print "}"                              }  # Right brace
' infile.foo
```

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it illustrates the basics of extracting the information you're interested in and reformatting/rearranging it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the line numbers are fixed width, just

```
cut -c11- file >file.new
```

If your final target is some sort of parsed JSON output, then whatever you are using to do the actual parsing is probably also very well equipped to skip the line numbers.